# How to use multiple tables and show the JSON result using SQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

Requirement is to fetch data from multiple table according to days and return it as multi-tier JSON as shown in images
[JSON Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kbik.png)
[Table Day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6NZv.png)[Table Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp6XL.png)[Table Place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL2Hc.png)[Table Hotel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44VBB.png)
I have added all the table schema. I need to show all the data mapped with the day table

[Route Details tbl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqlDu.png)

Comment: Result is link:
----------------
{
 "Days": [
    {
      "dayName": "Day 1",
      "routes": [
        {
          "routeName": "Airport"
        },
        {
          "routeName": "Simla"
        }
      ]
     }
   ]
}

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand the question like where route name will come from or what is joining key between two table but assuming its `trip_guid` you can use something like this with little tweaking

```
select JSON_OBJECT('Days', JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('day_name', a.day_name, 'routes', JSON_OBJECT('routeName', route_guid)))
  ) from tbl_temp_pack_day a
inner join tbl_temp_pack_day_route b on a.trip_guid=b.trip_guid
```